# call a method- inside success and to get json array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

I am using ajax and want to access the Json array inside the Success  to call another method. I am unable to access the Json array. empList - returns JSON ,. 1. Firstly i would like to know how to get array name which contains data inside success  .  2. I want to call removeemp in the success to remove one element from the JSON data.

```
   $("#emp").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
          $.ajax({

                url: empList,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "name": request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    //this.data.removeemp("EmpName", "Emplisttext.value");

                   response($.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                            label: item.EmpName,
                            value: item.EmpName
                        };
                    }));
                }


            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        highlight: true,
        multiple: true
    });

I have used: 
Array.Prototype.removeemp = function (name, value) {
    var array = $.map(this, function (v, i) {
    return v[name] === value ? null : v;
  });
  this.length = 0; //clear original array
 this.push.apply(this, array); //push all elements except one to delete
}
```

Comment: don't use **this** inside a another method or better to assign **this** to any **variable**  and use that **variable**.like
 **this =that;**
**that.data.removeemp("emp","value");**

Comment: I tried that... Might be silly... Where should I declare say var me = this;

Comment: @yugi and where should I declare removeemp?

Comment: $("#emp").autocomplete({
var that=this;})

Comment: @yugi that is throwing an error  :expected, } expected

Comment: for your error : `$("#emp").autocomplete({ var that=this});`

Comment: @Sebastien.Beaulieu I tried that. Still throwing the error as we have source in the next line

Comment: @Sebastien.Beaulieu Also alert(data) is returning list of {[object, object], ..... [object, object]}. I want to call removeemp inside success